# Use checkstyle to throw error for lombok annotations

Tags: checkstyle, lombok

I want to throw errors when the @Builder annotation from lombok is used. I couldn't find docs regarding Lombok annotations on checkstyle's website.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: If using checkstyle is not a hard requirement, you could also use lombok's configuration system to disallow certain features within a project. E.g., you could disallow `@Builder` by setting `lombok.builder.flagUsage = error`.

Comment: Perhaps you can give a try to [Forbidden API Checker](https://github.com/policeman-tools/forbidden-apis)? You can simply deny any usage of `@Builder`. It's compatible with Ant, Maven, or Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Check out and configure [IllegalImport](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#IllegalImport) and [ImportControl](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#ImportControl) to block the imports.

For star imports, you can either disallow star imports with [AvoidStarImport](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#AvoidStarImport), use [sevntu](https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle)'s ForbidAnnotationCheck, or use [RegexpSingleline](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_regexp.html#RegexpSingleline) as a last resort.

Comment: I still can't prevent the behaviour if the import is Lombok.* right? Because usually we use other 2 or 3 annotations apart from the Builder.